# I am not able to to understand how to use useReferenceArrayInputContext in ReactAdmin

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-admin

I am very new to React and ReactAdmin. Could someone share an example of how to use `useReferenceArrayInputContext` in React Admin code. Seems like there is no documentation and examples on how to use the same. Advance Thanks

[useReferenceArrayInputContext](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#usereferencearrayinputcontext)

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    Edit,
    SimpleForm,
    ReferenceArrayInput,
    SelectArrayInput,
    useReferenceArrayInputContext,
} from 'react-admin';

const NameSelectArrayInput = props => {
    const {
        choices, // An array of records matching both the current input value and the filters
        error, // A potential error that may have occured while fetching the data
        warning, // A potential warning regarding missing references
        loaded, // boolean that is false until the data is available
        loading, // boolean that is true on mount, and false once the data was fetched
        setFilter, // a callback to update the filters, e.g. setFilters({ q: 'query' })
        setPagination, // a callback to change the pagination, e.g. setPagination({ page: 2, perPage: 50 })
        setSort, // a callback to change the sort, e.g. setSort({ field: 'name', order: 'DESC' })
        setSortForList, // a callback to set the sort with the same signature as the one from the ListContext. This is required to avoid breaking backward compatibility and will be removed in v4
    } = useReferenceArrayInputContext(props);

    return <SelectArrayInput choices={choices} {...props} optionText="name" />;
};

const PostEdit = props => {
    return (
        <Edit {...props}>
            <SimpleForm>
                <ReferenceArrayInput source="tag_ids" reference="tags">
                    <NameSelectArrayInput />
                </ReferenceArrayInput>
            </SimpleForm>
        </Edit>
    );
};
```